# Paragraph spaces in email template function

Tags: functions, email

I am using this function to send an email to users after publishing, but I need to add paragraph spaces between text.`<br>` doesn't seem to work in this context.

```
function wpse_366380_email_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( 'publish' == $new_status && ( 'auto-draft' == $old_status || 'pending' == $old_status ) ) {
    
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
        $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.",
        Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published. Ps: Please review the article below <br>
        View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."";
        wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You may find this SO thread relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character

Comment: thank you, but I don't understand why my question wants to be closed, I think I have been very specific

Comment: Yes, your question is clear and specific. It just happens not to be unique or only applicable to WordPress, but more of a generic PHP question, i.e. how to add new lines / line breaks to a text string, which are considered off-topic on this forum - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic